# How to specify the bash environment to use the Numeric module for Python?

Tags: python, linux, module, path, numeric

I am trying to manually install the (now deprecated but I need it) Numeric module for python.
I use Mandriva 2010. 
I have downloaded Numeric 24.2, used:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install --prefix=/other/directory
```

So now, in /other/directory, I have the following directories:

```
./include/python2.6/Numeric/
./lib/python2.6/site-packages/Numeric/
```

All I need now is to configure correctly my PYTHONPATH and/or LD_LIBRARY_PATH to make it find my Numeric module. Problem is I just can't figure it. I have tried some common values, but have always received the same negative answer:

```
import Numeric
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Numeric
```

What are the correct parameters? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find somebody to sorted it right!

To use Numeric, you have to add `/other/directory/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Numeric` to `$PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

`$PYTHONPATH` should include the entry `/other/directory/lib/python2.6/site-packages`, and if a native library was installed in `/other/directory/lib`,  then `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should include `/other/directory/lib`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. I have found the answer (see below). What do you call a native library? shared object .so files?